# Taylor Remainder proof

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I stumbled upon this site that explains how to obtain the error function for the n-th Taylor polynomial: http://davidlowryduda.com/an-intuitive-overview-of-taylor-series/

By the Mean Value Theorem:

$$f'(x) = f'(0) + f''(c)x$$

We rewrite in t and integrate both sides:

$$f'(t) = f'(0) + f''(c)t\tag{1}$$
$$\int_0^xf'(t)dt = \int_0^x[f'(0) + f''(c)t]dt$$
$$f(x)-f(0) = xf'(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(c)x^2$$

I don't understand how we can integrate $\int_0^xf''(c)tdt$.
Isn't $c$ a function of $t$ since $0<c<t$ in equation (1)?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a function of t. the theorem tells you that there exists some c with the wanted property. once you have it it's only a constant.

Comment: How is it not a function when it depends on t?

Comment: c lies between 0 and x and thats also where you're integrating. you fix your x then find the c that satisfies the theorem. this c = c(x) is fixed, x is also fixed thats why you switch the integrating variable from x to t then integrate up to x.

Comment: But equation (1) is only true if c lies between 0 and t; it comes from the mean value theorem.